# select between two dates in access using vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to export report from my access database between two dates my querie `"Select * from [Income] where ([Income_Date] Between '" & from_date.Value.ToShortDateString & "' And '" & To_Date.Value.ToShortDateString & "')"`
But now when I select date 20/05/2018 to 02/06/2018 it displays record before 20/05/2018 not between. please help

Comment: First things first, learn how to write a parameterised query. Once you've done that, let's see whether the same issue remains.

Comment: The first reason to use parameterized queries is to protect you from sql injection. The second one, I would say, is to make your life easier with dates within queries. (Further advantages included)

Comment: access date filters here - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762...they use pound signs...but you should be using parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

Your have problem with date format (20/05/2018 vs 2018/05/20).

As far as `"20"` is greater than `"02"`, `"20/05/2018"` is greater than `"02/06/2018"` because you forces Access to interpret it as string not a date.

to solve the problem force Access to interpret it as date by using `#` instead of `'`.

Change your query to `Select * from [Income] where ([Income_Date] Between #" & from_date.Value.ToShortDateString & "# And #" & To_Date.Value.ToShortDateString & "#)`.

Comment: nope same output when i select date 23/05/2018 to 03/06/2018 it displays result of before 23/05/2018